# Automatic generation of a value C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make automatic generation of a value in a class in C++.

This is Shape.h

```
#pragma once
class Shape
{
public:
    Shape();
    ~Shape();
    // Return ID of the Shape
    virtual int getId();
    // Return area of the Shape
    virtual double getArea();
protected:
    static int _id;
    double _area;
    // Compute the area of the shape
    virtual void compArea() = 0;
};
```

And this is Shape.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Shape.h"


Shape::Shape()
{
_id++;     //ID is incremented in every instance
_area = 0.0;
}


Shape::~Shape()
{
    std::cout << "Distruttore Shape" << std::endl;
}


// Return ID of the Shape
int Shape::getId()
{
    return _id;
}


// Return area of the Shape
double Shape::getArea()
{
    return _area;
}
```

And when I compile I receive:

error LNK2001: external symbol "public: static int Shape::_id" (?_id@Shape@@2HA) unresolved

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for help :)

Comment: I think you want something like auto-generated id, in case for that, you should provide another class member variable like, `int real_id`, then on the constructor side, assign it to the static one `real_id = _id++;`, then this one should be the return variable of `getId()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define the static variable in **cpp** file:

```
int Shape::_id;
```

You should do this in the same namespace in which you've defined `Shape`.

Note that `static int _id;` inside the class is called *declaration*, which means, it is an announcement to the compiler that `_id` as variable of type `int` exists somewhere — *where* exactly? the compiler doesn't bother with this question.The announcement/declaration itself doesn't make the variable to exist in memory. To make it exist in the memory, you need to *define* it.

Also note that the compiler needs only the declaration and the linker needs the definition — i.e the linker asks the question "where exactly?" which is why it needs the definition which *ensures* its existence.